# Java: socket not getting input

Tags: java, sockets, input, io, output

So, I'm making a tic tac toe project and I'm having a problem with the network part, it's all finished, only missing the part that connects players with each other, this is the class with the problem:

```
public class Enemy implements Runnable{
    private static Socket enemy;

    public Enemy(Socket sock){
        enemy = sock;
    }

    public static void passaJogada(int xPos, int yPos){
        try {
            PrintWriter saida = new PrintWriter(enemy.getOutputStream());
            String x = "" + xPos;
            saida.println(x);
            String y = "" + yPos;
            System.out.print(x + y);
            saida.println(y);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Ocorreu um erro!");
        }    
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader entrada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(enemy.getInputStream()));
            while(!EndGameWindow.getEnd()) {    
                int x = Integer.parseInt(entrada.readLine());
                int y = Integer.parseInt(entrada.readLine());
                GameWindow.gameButton[x][y].fazerJogada(x,y);
            }
            entrada.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Um errro ocorreu!");
        }
    }
}
```

and I don't have a clue of what is going on, all I know is that the PrintWriter is writing but the BufferedReader is not reading.

Just ignore the portuguese name of the variables and methods.

Comment: Is the other side of the Socket writing the proper delim for `readLine()` (eg a new line character)?

Comment: The other side of the socket is the passaJogada method and it is printing with the println method a string with only an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the API for [PrintWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html), in particular the single parameter `OutputStream` constructor you are using:

> Creates a new PrintWriter, **without** automatic line flushing, from an existing OutputStream.

In other words, the `PrintWriter` is buffered and needs to be flushed. To enable automatic line flushing, use the appropriate constructor

```
PrintWriter saida = new PrintWriter(enemy.getOutputStream(), true);
```

...or explicitly flush the PrintWriter:

```
....
saida.println(y);
saida.flush();
```

Comment: Wow, it worked!! Thank you dude, sorry I can't vote up your post.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming that you want players to play with each other even if none of them are sitting on the computer where the server "game" is. In that case what you should do is to separate the game from the networking. I am going to also assume that you have all the game part working like it should. So here is what you can do. 
1) First make a class where where only the connecting to the server part is taking place , you can name it server(look below in example code).
2) Make another class to make object of these clients (in your case players).(again look at the code below) 
3) Then you can have them interact with the game.

If you are having trouble fixing it, let me know maybe i can help you with more detail.

You simple server part .

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * Created by baljit on 03.05.2015.
 * @author Baljit Sarai
 */

public class Server {
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    public static List<ClientConnection> clientConnectionList = new ArrayList<ClientConnection>();
    public Server() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(12345);
            System.out.println("Server started");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong");
        }
    }




public void serve(){
    Socket clientSocket;
    try {
        while((clientSocket = serverSocket.accept()) != null){
            System.out.println("got client from"+clientSocket.getInetAddress());
            ClientConnection clientConnection = new ClientConnection(clientSocket);
            clientConnectionList.add(clientConnection);
            ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler(clientConnection,serverSocket);
            clientHandler.start();
        }
    }catch (IOException ioe){
        System.out.println("Something went wrong");
     }
    }
}
```

The clientConnection in this case can be the pllayer object you should make just to make things easier for your self.

The clientHandler is the class that can handle each player at the same time.

The "clientConnectionList" here is just to store the connections so you know where to find them.

So here is the ClientConnection class.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * Created by baljit on 03.05.2015.
 * @author Baljit Sarai
 */
public class ClientConnection {
    private Socket connection;
    private DataInputStream streamIn;
    private DataOutputStream streamOut;
    private BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream;
    public ClientConnection(Socket socket){
        connection = socket;
        try{

            bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            streamIn = new DataInputStream(bufferedInputStream);
            streamOut = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        }catch (IOException ioe){
            System.out.println("Something went wrong when trying create the Connection Object");
        }
    }

    public boolean isBound(){
        return connection.isBound();
    }    
    public DataInputStream getStreamIn() {
        return streamIn;
    }

    public DataOutputStream getStreamOut() {
        return streamOut;
    }

    public void close(){
        try{

            connection.close();
        }catch (IOException ioe){
            System.out.print("Something went wrong trying to close the connection");
        }
    }

    public String getAddress(){
        return connection.getInetAddress().toString();
    }




}
```

And here is the ClientHandler Class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * Created by baljit on 03.05.2015.
 * @author Baljit Sarai
 */
public class ClientHandler extends Thread{
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    String data;
    ClientConnection connection;

    public ClientHandler(ClientConnection clientConnection, ServerSocket serverSocket) {
        connection = clientConnection;
    }

    public void makeMove(String data){
        //This is where you put the logic for how the server can 
        //interpetate the readed data to a game move

    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("ClientHandler running");
        try{
            while(connection.isBound()){
                data= connection.getStreamIn().readUTF();
                this.makeMove(data);
            }
            connection.close();
        }catch (IOException ioe){
            System.out.println("Connection dead "+connection.getAddress());
            Server.clientConnectionList.remove(connection);
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know how it is working out for you. Maybe i can help you better :) good luck :)

Comment: I already have an class just for the networking, it has some javafx in it for UI, if you want i can post all the code for you to help me (if you can).

Comment: I am new too. I am  student yet . But I like helping and try solving such problems . link me the code so can atleast see and maybe I can improve and help you with the code.

Comment: 1. You haven't shown how to send.  2. `Socket.isBound()` will never return false after connection. It is not a valid test for connection validity. There isn't one: however `readUTF()` throws `EOFException` at end of stream, and you aren't catching it and handling it correctly.

Comment: I was just trying to show the bacis way to connect people to a socket . I know the code needs correcting . I was just trying to help him. I can polish the code if you like.